# I am actively running Windows 2016 Hyper-V *WITHOUT* SLAT *OR* VMX - how is this possible?

Tags: hyper-v, windows-server-2016, hyper-v-server-2016

Correct me if I am wrong, but one of the more defining features of Hyper-V on Windows 2016 is that, like Windows 8, the INTEL features known as SLAT and VMX [have become a *required* feature](https://technet.microsoft.com/windows-server-docs/compute/hyper-v/system-requirements-for-hyper-v-on-windows) in order to [even install the Hyper-V service in the first place](http://windowsitpro.com/hyper-v/hyper-v-requirements-windows-server-2016).

So how come I am able to install and run Hyper-V without SLAT or VMX?

Proof:

[image: Windows Server 2016 running Hyper-V without SLAT]

Observe, please, the CoreInfo output which clearly displays this system as *not* possessing the SLAT *or* VMX technology. And yet, I have Hyper-V installed and 3 VMs up and running quite merrily.

Just genuinely curious and confused, as everything out there says that CoreInfo will definitively tell you if you don’t have SLAT and VMX (an asterisk means yes, a dash, no), and that Server 2016 will not allow you to install the Hyper-V service (much less run VMs) without SLAT and VMX.

Answer (score 4):

I'm a bit new to the SLAT stuff, but from what I have read, you have to run coreinfo *BEFORE* you install a Hypervisor.  It is possible you do have SLAT but coreinfo is reading it incorrectly because you have Hyper-V installed already.

Comment: Yes, that is exactly it. Like many, the OP does not really uderstand Hyper-V - the moment you install it, your "desktop" is already in a VM (VM0).

Answer (score 1):

Your processor supports Extended Page Tables (EPT) that is also known as Second Level Address Translation (SLAT).

https://ark.intel.com/products/52580/Intel-Xeon-Processor-X5647-12M-Cache-2_93-GHz-5_86-GTs-Intel-QPI

Answer (score 0):

Your processor does support SLAT. Although it is not enabled in the BIOS, it recognizes that it is present. Otherwise, it would not even let you install Hyper-V.